# Entity type IdentityRole is not part of the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm currently trying to add roles to my application and I'am getting this error "Entity type IdentityRole is not part of the current context". I previously had the same error except with AppRole but I resolved that issue by including all the parameters after the IdentityDbContext in the AppIdentityDbContext class but I cannot fix this one,thanks for the help

This is the line I get the error on

```
ClaimsIdentity ident = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

DbContext Class

```
 public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, AppRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
    {
        public AppIdentityDbContext() : base("ProGP_Db") { }

        static AppIdentityDbContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<AppIdentityDbContext>(new IdentityDbInit());
        }
        public static AppIdentityDbContext Create()
        {
            return new AppIdentityDbContext();
        }
    }
    public class IdentityDbInit
    : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<AppIdentityDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(AppIdentityDbContext context)
        {
            PerformInitialSetup(context);
            base.Seed(context);
        }
        public void PerformInitialSetup(AppIdentityDbContext context)
        {
            // initial configuration will go here
        }
    }
```

AppUserManager Class

```
public class AppUserManager : UserManager<User,string>
{

    public AppUserManager(IUserStore<User> store): base(store){}


    public static AppUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<AppUserManager> options,IOwinContext context)
    {
        AppIdentityDbContext db = context.Get<AppIdentityDbContext>();
        AppUserManager manager = new AppUserManager(new UserStore<User>(db));

        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true
        };


        return manager;
    }
}
```

AppRoleManager

```
public class AppRoleManager : RoleManager<AppRole>,IDisposable
{
    public AppRoleManager(RoleStore<AppRole> store):base(store)
    { }


    public static AppRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<AppRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        //AppIdentityDbContext db = context.Get<AppIdentityDbContext>();
        //AppRoleManager manager = new AppRoleManager(new RoleStore<AppRole>(db));
        return new AppRoleManager(new RoleStore<AppRole>(context.Get<AppIdentityDbContext>()));

        //return manager;
    }
}
```

AppRole class

```
  public class AppRole:IdentityRole
{
    public AppRole():base() { }


    public AppRole(string name) : base (name)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the UserStore I had IdentityRole explicitly declared,I created another class extending from UserStore which solved the issue.

```
public class AppUserStore<TUser> : UserStore<TUser, Role, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, IUserStore<TUser>, IUserStore<TUser, string>, IDisposable where TUser : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser {

public AppUserStore(DbContext context) :base(context) {}     }
```